# Stereographic projection $S^3 \to \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, riemannian-geometry, spherical-coordinates, stereographic-projections

I think I can find a stereographic projection $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\} \to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\setminus\{[0,1]\}$ using spherical coordinates:

it should be something like this $$(\theta,\phi)\to [1,2\tan (\frac \pi 4 + \frac \theta 2)e^{i\phi}]$$

Now I'm trying to find a projection $S^3 \setminus {(0,0,0,1)} \to \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \{Re(z_1=0)\}$

How can you express these projections in cartesian coordinates?

thank you

Comment: What is $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)\setminus\{\operatorname{Re}(z_1=0)\}$ supposed to mean? To me the $\{\operatorname{Re}(z_1=0)\}$ part would denote the set of all vectors with a zero real part in their first coordinate. But as part of a projective space, this doesn't make a lot of sense, since a change in representative could change the phase of the first coordinate. Perhaps you should put your notation in words as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that lack of precision. Could it be $\{Re(z_1=0)\}= \{[0,z_2,z_3]\}=\{[0,1,z_3/z_2],[0,0,1]|z_3/z_2\in \mathbb{R}\}$ ? I'm just guessing because the text of the exercise is written more or less as i reported.

Comment: If you require $z_1=0$ and either $z_3/z_2\in\mathbb R$ or $z_2=0$, then you are essentially in $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$. Judging from the dimensions, the exercise probably meant $$\frac{\mathbb C^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}}{\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}}$$ i.e. the set of all pairs of complex numbers, but only with real multiples identified. Which is essentially equivalent to $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$ so it is three-dimensional as well, matching $S^3$. Calling this thing $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ would be a serious mistake though, in my opinion, since neither the dimension nor the base field matches.